# How to retrieve texts for CheckedItems in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckBoxList which contain dynamic data.Now i want to get the list of selected item from CheckBoxList. i am using following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chkTblListDb001.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (chkTblListDb001.GetItemChecked(i))
    {
          FirstTableSelectedColumns += chkTblListDb001.Items[i].ToString() + ",";
          MessageBox.Show(FirstTableSelectedColumns);
    }
}
```

but is return (in FirstTableSelectedColumns variable) "System.Data.DataRowView,System.Data.DataRowView,"

When I am using the this code

```
string test = "you've selected :";

foreach (ListItem item in theCheckBoxList.Items)
{
    test += item.Selected ? item.Value + ", " : "";
}
labelResult.Text = test;
```

its give me the following error that

> ListItem not found.

Comment: You must show how you bind that list but basically,you'll need to cast `chkTblListDb001.Items[i]` to `DataRowView` and then get the `DataRowView` column you want to show, something like `((DataRowView)chkTblListDb001.Items[i])[0].ToString()`

Comment: Windows forms doesn't have a `CheckBoxList` control. Do you mean `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: yes @ Reza Aghaei I mean was CheckedListBox.

Comment: thankx @Pikoh your given code worked for me :)

Comment: You're welcome... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution is  ((DataRowView)chkTblListDb001.Items[i])[0].ToString()

```
 string FirstTableSelectedColumns = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < chkTblListDb001.Items.Count; i++)
            {
              if (chkTblListDb001.GetItemChecked(i))
                 {
                 //FirstTableSelectedColumns += chkTblListDb001.Items[i].ToString() + ",";
                   FirstTableSelectedColumns += ((DataRowView)chkTblListDb001.Items[i])[0].ToString() + ",";
                   MessageBox.Show(FirstTableSelectedColumns);
                 }
             }
```

Thankx to @Pikoh

Comment: Use `GetItemText` to find the text and use `string.Join` to join items of a string list.

Answer (score 4):

To get text of an item in [`CheckedListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use [`GetItemText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

It doesn't matter what is the type of item, if you have used `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` it uses `DisplayMember` to return text, otherwise it uses `ToString` method of item.

Here is an example of what you are looking for, a comma-separated list of checked item texts:

```
var texts = this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<object>()
                .Select(x => this.checkedListBox1.GetItemText(x));

MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", texts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **CheckedItems** method.

```
       StringBuilder sbCheckedItems = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var cbx in chkTblListDb001.CheckedItems)
        {
            sbCheckedItems.Append(cbx.ToString() + ",");
        }
        MessageBox.Show(sbCheckedItems.ToString());
```

Comment: If the type of Item is an object, then you will receive result of `ToString()` of the object, which in this case for OP is `System.Data.DataRowView`, since it seems he is using a `DataTable` as `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, add this class to your project

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class CheckedListBoxExtensions
{
    public static string CheckedItemsJoined(this CheckedListBox sender)
    {
        var Result = from singleItem in sender.Items.OfType<string>().Where(
                         (item, index) =>
                         {
                             return sender.GetItemChecked(index);
                         }
                     )
                     select singleItem;

        return string.Join(",", Result.ToList<string>());
    }
}
```

Now in the form, use code modeled after this (meaning you need to change the names of the controls to match your controls.

```
someLabel.Text = checkedListBox1.CheckedItemsJoined();
```

Hope this is what you are after.

Comment: If the item is not of type of string, such code returns nothing. The most stable solution is using `GetItemText` method.